# Center audio control vertically in div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to center the audio control vertically in its `div` but have not been successfully able to:

```
<div style="height: 370px; border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; text-align: center;">
    <audio controls>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/G6ssK/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to wrap the `div` inside a wrapper element and than use `display: table;` and make your inner `div` `display: table-cell;` and use `vertical-align: middle;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6ssK/2/)

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 370px; 
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; 
}

.holder {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also, avoid inline styles, use *classes* and *ids* instead

---

Other way you can achieve this is by using CSS Positioning techniques where we set the parent element to `position: relative;` and than we set the child element to `position: absolute;` where `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` are set to `0` and also make sure you use `margin: auto;` there...

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6ssK/3/)

```
.wrapper {
    height: 370px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper audio {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: In your first demo, I didn't know that you could have a table-cell directly below a table without a table-row.

Comment: @AndroidDev yes, and it's completely valid

Answer (score 2):

The following is a `css` alternative which makes the audio center to the div.

```
audio{
position:relative;
top:calc(50% - 30px)    //30px is the height of the audio element.
}
```

Comment: great idea, although I think to properly centre it vertically, it should be calculated as -16px (i.e. half the height, which seems to be 32px, at least in Chrome, at the time of writing). Also there's a syntax error - you forgot the `;` after the end of the calc, but other than that, this is a neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G6ssK/4/)**

**css**

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 370px;
    width: 370px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;

}

#cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```